# Printmaker plugin cuts off HTML when rendering PDF link

Tags: pdf, plugin-printmaker, dompdf

I’ve got a funny Printmaker issue here that I hope you can help me with!

I’m using the following code to generate a link to a PDF:

```
{% set vars = { title: supportGuides.title, body: supportGuides.body } %}

{% set settings = { orientation : 'portrait', filename:supportGuides.slug~'.pdf' } %}

{% set pdf = craft.printmaker.pdfFromTemplate('support-guides/download', vars, settings) %}

<a href=“{{ pdf.url }}" target="_blank">Download PDF Support Guide</a>
```

In my HTML output, the beginning of the line is stripped out inexplicably:

```
https://mysite.dev/Printmaker/support-guide.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF Support Guide</a>
```

How can I prevent the opening tag from being cut out like that?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your server setup, DOMPDF might be resetting the output buffer when the PDF is generated. This is a fairly rare issue, but I have heard of it before.

**Solution: Try moving the Printmaker PDF-generation code to the top of the template before any output.**

For example, at the top of the template...

```
{% set pdfUrl = craft.printmaker.pdfFromTemplate('support-guides/download', vars, settings).url %}
```

...and then later, in your output content...

```
<a href="{{ pdfUrl }}" target="_blank">Download PDF Support Guide</a>
```

Comment: The code is within a for loop so i cannot really put it at the beginning as it's dependent on other logic.

However, would the same affect be achieved by putting it in a Macro and returning the html into the template?

Comment: I _think_ as long as the PDF generation happens on a separate _line_ from your HTML output, it'll avoid that issue. Does it work if you use the code from my answer inside your loop?

Comment: Ah! Yes, that worked (though your code sample says pdfUrl and your actual var name is pdf!) Thanks Michael!!

Comment: That's what I get for copy/pasting from old support emails. Fixed!